# Sometimes to find an answer to a short question you have to travel far. Sometimes not

Tags: lateral-thinking

This one's simple:

When and where is con the opposite of sin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the where is:

> In Spain? con meaning with in Spanish, and sin meaning without

Not sure specifically when though

> I guess if ordering something that had the option of with/without something, that might be one example

Or maybe there's second meaning I'm missing for the when part

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer

> In front of a K

Reasoning

> **Con**k can mean "nose", a protrusion on the face.
>  **Sin**k generally refers to a recess.